# How do I get rigidbody physics + constraints to interact with a mesh animated with an armature?

Tags: animation, armature, rigid-body-simulation, pose-mode, rigidbody

In my scene I have 4 "cards" and 1 "stick". The cards are connected to the eachother and the stick with point constraints: https://streamable.com/jtglq
They are interacting correctly on their own.

I would like to have the stick be animated by an armature. I cannot find a way to get the physics system to interact with the changes in the mesh via animating the armature: https://streamable.com/f22h6

Assuming what I want to do is possible, how do I do it in blender 2.8x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer over discord but I figured I'd post it here to help anyone who finds this in the future.

Connect the "stick" to the armature using object constraints instead of the armature modifier.

[image]